# location block not working properly Nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx, ruby-on-rails, centos7

I have a `wordpress` site , let's say `domain.com` working on `nginx` . now i have a rails application running on same server with port `4567` . I want to bypass it using `nginx` location block in my `domain.com` . So far i have the following :

```
   location = /abc_app
    {
        client_max_body_size 45M;
        try_files      $uri =404;
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:4567;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

When i try to access it using `domain.com/abc_app` it give me `404`
Any help will be much appreciating

Comment: Do you get nginx 404 or rails 404?

Comment: nginx 404 .....

Comment: You are telling it to give a `404` with `try_files      $uri =404;` It is going to try the local directory and if it can't find your file give you a `404`

Comment: I commented that line and still giving 404 , what else should i try

Comment: What URI are you trying to access on `http://127.0.0.1:4567`? Is it `http://127.0.0.1:4567/abc_app`?